# What is a QT Plugin?

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, qt4

What is a QT Plugin? What are differences between a qt plugin and a custom made qt library?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*AFAIK Qt plugins are implemented as shared libraries* (.so on Unix/Linux and DLLs on Windows). The differences between them are the same as with *plugins* and *libraries* in general.

What this means is that, ***a plug-in architecture is independent of the linking method***.
They tend to be thought of as plug-in/dynamic linking and non-plug-in/static linking.

A core application *specifies an interface and data exchange contract* (i.e. an API) through which separate modules can interact with the application and expose functionality through the application. Just shipping new modules in DLLs ***does not address the need of a way for the application itself to discover these DLLs*** and to know how to execute the logic within.  This is the essence of a plugin architecture. In general, DLL's expose only a list of procedures or functions.  Variables, classes, objects inside the dll are not directly accessible to outside processes.  Writing a plugin involves moving most or all of the relevant code into the DLL, where all variables and objects can be directly referenced.

Something like *Eclipse*, wherein you place you plugin in a pre-defined directory and the next time you click on some Menu you see new entries. All this without *restarting* your `app` or running a new version of the `exe`.

Answer (score 6):

The feature you call a Qt Plugin is formally a framework inside Qt that allows developers to propose a plugin system for their application. Qt Plugin handles the dynamic loading of the plugins that can be used through the plugin interface by the application. You can look at [Qt Plugin documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/plugins-howto.html) for more information and examples.